# Converter um arquivo excel (xls, xlsx) para PDF

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Eu tenho que converter um arquivo excel (xls, xlsx) para PDF, no entanto estou procurando uma maneira melhor, no entanto não tenho certeza se o exemplo a seguir é o melhor para mim:

https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/use-excel-api-to-convert-spreadsheets-to-pdfs-in-java

Não encontrei bons posts e respostas aqui, alguém tem alguns exemplos melhores:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572244/java-save-xls-file-as-pdf

De uma forma simples eu só preciso converter excel para pdf em java da melhor maneira possível, sem ler o excel todo.

Eu encontrei este exemplo, que faz exatamente o que eu preciso, no entanto, não posso usar isso por causa da licença:

https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/sample-java-code-to-convert-excel-to-pdf-using-jofficeconvert/

Desde já, obrigado !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muitos testes, consegui convence-los que a primeira solução que usei estava correta:

```
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.*;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
    import java.util.Iterator;
   import com.itextpdf.text.*;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

    public class excel2pdf {  
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

                    FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\excel_to_pdf.xls"));
                    // Read workbook into HSSFWorkbook
                    HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
                    // Read worksheet into HSSFSheet
                    HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
                    // To iterate over the rows
                    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator();
                    //We will create output PDF document objects at this point
                    Document iText_xls_2_pdf = new Document();
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(iText_xls_2_pdf, new FileOutputStream("Excel2PDF_Output.pdf"));
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.open();
                    //we have two columns in the Excel sheet, so we create a PDF table with two columns
                    //Note: There are ways to make this dynamic in nature, if you want to.
                    PdfPTable my_table = new PdfPTable(2);
                    //We will use the object below to dynamically add new data to the table
                    PdfPCell table_cell;
                    //Loop through rows.
                    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                                    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); //Fetch CELL
                                            switch(cell.getCellType()) { //Identify CELL type
                                                    //you need to add more code here based on
                                                    //your requirement / transformations
                                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                                    //Push the data from Excel to PDF Cell
                                                     table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                                                     //feel free to move the code below to suit to your needs
                                                     my_table.addCell(table_cell);
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            //next line
                                    }

                    }
                    //Finally add the table to PDF document
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.add(my_table);                       
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.close();                
                    //we created our pdf file..
                    input_document.close(); //close xls
            }
    }
```

Obrigado aos que me ajudaram !

Answer (score 1):

Você pode converter Excel em PDF apenas alterando o tipo de arquivo na hora de Salvar Como. Altere o tipo de arquivo para PDF. Logo abaixo do nome do arquivo.

[image: janela de salvar como]

Comment: Não é aceitável, ou seja, o processo tem que ser automatizado, já é salvo um PDF, mas eles querem que salve a partir do Excel, como se eu fosse enviar para impressora, já fiz isso no passado criando uma impressora virtual com API POI e Itext, mas não aceitam dessa vez, tem que ser como o serviço save as pdf, mas não posso clicar no Excel, Também já fiz Iterando o arquivo Excel com Itext, mas querem salvando sem criar impressora vitual, encontrei isso na internet https://github.com/caryyu/excel2pdf

Comment: Mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda !